# div with fixed position and css attribute "animation", it doesn't animate with the "transform: translateY(0%)" property when I add class dynamically

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create an animation to a `div` with `fixed` position. basically I want that when 5 seconds pass a `class` is added to this `div` and an `animation` is made, but for some reason, it is not happening.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Modal() {
  const modal = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      modal.current.classList.add("modalShow");
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  return <div id="modal" ref={modal} className="modalContainer "></div>;
}


.modalContainer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  animation: all 5s ease-out;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.modalShow {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
.modalHide {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

this is my live code:

[Live Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-worker-db0qz)

thanks!

Comment: I think you are confusing `animation` for `transition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `@keyframes`.

Change:

```
animation: all 5s ease-out;
```

to:

```
transition: all 5s ease-out;
```